# Java KeyListener Issue

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm making a a program where (for now) there is a running back that is controlled by the arrow keys, and a linebacker to stop him (will be able to move toward the running back automatically). I was able to get the running back to move, but it's not working now. Here's the code I have so far:

JFrame class:

```
    public class FootballFrame extends JFrame {

            Panels panels;

            public FootballFrame() throws IOException{

                setTitle("Tackle Breaking Running Back");

                panels = new Panels();

                add(panels);

                setSize(1166, 795);

                setResizable(false);

                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                setVisible(true); 

        }

    }
```

Panels Class:

```
    public class Panels extends JPanel{

         private FootballField field;
         private ScoreboardPanel score;

         public Panels() throws IOException{

           setLayout(new BorderLayout());

           score = new ScoreboardPanel();
           score.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
           add(score, "North");

           field = new FootballField();
           field.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

           add(field, "Center");


      }

  }
```

FootballField Class:

```
public class FootballField extends JPanel implements KeyListener{


    private Image footballField;
    private ImageIcon runningBackImage, linebackerImage;
    private JButton runningBack, linebacker;

    public FootballField() throws IOException{
        super();
        //Set layout to null to be able to freely position objects
        setLayout(null);

        //Creates the football field image
        footballField =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("footballfield.jpeg");
        //Creates the running back iage
        runningBackImage = new ImageIcon("football_player.png");
        //Sets the button to be the runningBack image
        runningBack = new JButton(runningBackImage);
        //Allows us to place the running back using null layout
        //Lookup the first part with Rectangle and Point, and check why we need preferredSize
       runningBack.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(925, 325), runningBack.getPreferredSize()));
        //These 2 lines make sure that the button is the exact size of the image
        runningBack.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        runningBack.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        //Add the running back to the screen
        add(runningBack);

        //Create the linebacker
        linebackerImage = new ImageIcon("linebacker.png");
        //Set the button to be the linebacker image
        linebacker = new JButton(linebackerImage);
        //Allow to place the linebacker using the null layout
        linebacker.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(350, 325), linebacker.getPreferredSize()));
        //Make sure the button is the same size as the image
        linebacker.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        linebacker.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        //Add the linebacker to the screen
        add(linebacker);

        //Add the listeners, and make sure keys are being recorded
       setFocusable(true);
       addKeyListener(this);
       requestFocusInWindow();

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //Draws the image created in the constructor
        g.drawImage(footballField, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();

        if(k == e.VK_LEFT) {
            Point currentPoint = runningBack.getLocation();
            runningBack.setLocation(currentPoint.x - 4, currentPoint.y);

        }
        else if(k == e.VK_RIGHT) {
            Point currentPoint = runningBack.getLocation();
            runningBack.setLocation(currentPoint.x + 4, currentPoint.y);
        }
        else if(k == e.VK_UP) {
            Point currentPoint = runningBack.getLocation();
            runningBack.setLocation(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y - 4);

         }
        else if(k == e.VK_DOWN) {
            Point currentPoint = runningBack.getLocation();
            runningBack.setLocation(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y + 4);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

The Scoreboard class didn't seem to have an effect on the keylistener working, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: what is not working? error message? wrong behaviour?

Comment: The running back in the FootballField panel isn't responding to the key presses

Comment: This is a common issue with `KeyListener`, which is best solved by using the [Key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, that's what I need to fix this then. Thanks!